# Is MochaHost as good as it sounds?

Tags: web-hosting, asp.net, windows, .net

It's time for me to find a new web host, and I'm a bit overwhelmed by the selection.  I need a Windows host.  One provider that seems to stand out is [MochaHost](http://www.mochahost.com/webhosting_windows.php).  Here are a few of the things that look amazing to me:

- **2** free domains for life.  ***2!!***
- MS SQL Support - Unlimited Databases
- 5,000 sites
- $3.33/month
- Unlimited everything (traffic, storage, domains, etc.)

Is MochaHost too good to be true?  Maybe it is notoriously unreliable (despite their 100% uptime guarantee)?  Are there other considerations I may be forgetting?

Comment: I recommend you never buy any host or domain from this place, because the access to their database always have problem and not available in most cases,
your website would load heavily, and finally when you ask for refund, they refuse to refund you, they owe me 130 USD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Unlimited' is not possible to achieve, it's more of a marketing gimmick. Although seems to be mostly assumed it means basically they let you use whatever till you hit some of the many limits in their TOS (ie, you might be hitting their CPU usage early when using loads of bandwidth, for scripts usage, etc), and more or less is becoming a common "term".

The domains matter tie you to that hosting, instead of having the freedom to change to another(you can, but there can be more delays and issues) if the hosting starts to lose speed, etc.

I tend to find good feedback on Hostgator, Hawkhost, Liquidwebs. Just recently have not checked.

Comment: Shared hosting also is more prone to sluggish performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

Please be warned and do not use Mochahost.com as they will not honor their contract and will sucker you in buying their cheap plans to later demand more payment from you (after your payment has settled) claiming you are using too many resources and forcing you to upgrade your plan. They will not refund you even with their guarantees.  Please review the Better Business Bureau for their F rating.

http://sanjose.bbb.org/Business-Report/Mochahost-235786

MOCHAHOST.COM REVIEW, COMPLAINT & CLASS ACTION LAWSUIT!
Mochahost prices are cheap but there is a reason which Mochahost will wrongfully force you to upgrade, after your payment settles (after 60 days), by suspending your account not providing you access to your own data. You can email elawcase@gmail.com for a Class Action Lawsuit against Mochahost.com, provide as much details and let us know if you are willing to attend court hearings in Santa Clara, California. Please continue to report Mochahost.com to the Santa Clara County District Attorney's office, BBB,  California Department of Justice, Office of the Attorney General (AG), the Internet Crime Complaint Center (IC3) which is a partnership between the Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI), the National White Collar Crime Center (NW3C), and the Bureau of Justice Assistance (BJA).  The FBI's IC3 Unit is organized to handle internet business fraud. All the statements below are true and are claims against Mochahost.com.

1. FALSE ADVERTISING - They claim they offer unlimited domains, unlimited space and unimited bandwidth.  But they will
2. SUSPEND YOUR ACCOUNT ANYTIME at will without warning and try to
3. FORCE YOU TO UPGRADE your account.  They do not give you unlimited bandwidth nor unlimited storage. This is false advertising which there should be a class action lawsuit against mochahost.com. Luring you to buy their cheap plans is a webhosting scam and trick which Mocahost uses to later try to force you to upgrade by suspending your account if you do not.
4. NOT HELPFUL online support - The online tech support is completely useless and they will terminate the chat as fast as they can and just tell you to write a support ticket.
5. NO PHONE. You cannot call them. This is one big warning sign for you. If you request they call you, you might have to wait a long time if they even call you back.
6. NOT FRIENDLY customer tech support. They are only friendly before you sign up.
7. Mochahost DOES NOT ADMIT FAULT. No matter how you prove there is a problem with the server, they will try their best to tell you nothing is wrong.  Perhaps this is their way to avoid any lawsuit or compensation for server down time and problems. They will find ways to blame your codes or anything possible so that they can avoid the responsibility. When you prove it to them, they will still not admit error, then tell you they cannot help you and ask you to write a support ticket. Complaints to Mochahost.com will only make them suspend your account which they will make up a reason. If you want an honest webhost, this isn't it. In fact, this is one of the least honest host and the worst web hosting company we have dealt with in the past 10 years.
8. Their SERVERS ARE NOT STABLE. The server has stalling issues or downtime about one time every two weeks on average.
9. Mochahost just DOES NOT CARE ABOUT THEIR OWN CUSTOMERS.  If you want to try them out, sign up for a short time period and you'll know exactly why Mochahost gets the most complaints of all web hosting companies.
10. CHECK THE BBB (Better Business Bureau  Email: info@bbbsilicon.org) to read their negative web hosting reviews and also make a complaint against Mochahost. They have plenty of complaints. Don't go with them because you think they are cheap. That is a big mistake. If you file a complaint against Mochahost with the BBB, type in Mochahost for their searched name. They have an F rating with the BBB http://sanjose.bbb.org/Business-Report/Mochahost-235786 .
11. Complaint to the BBB, Paypal,
12. SUE MOCHAHOST for their mistreatment and for being unethical. You can email elawcase@gmail.com and the more complaints the better for a CLASS ACTION LAWSUIT AGAINST MOCHAHOST.COM.
13. We recommend you contact the Santa Clara County District Attorney's office to file a complaint against the business since the business is located in the County of Santa Clara.  Many local district attorneys, through consumer fraud units, prosecute fraudulent practices in their communities.  You may contact the Santa Clara County District Attorney's office at the following: County of Santa Clara, Office of the District Attorney, 70 West Hedding Street, West Wing, San Jose, CA  95110, Telephone:  (408) 299-7400, Email:  webmaster@da.co.santa-clara.ca.us
14. We would also recommend that you contact the California Department of Justice, Office of the Attorney General (AG).  The AG's office establishes and operates projects and programs to protect consumers from fraudulent, unfair, and illegal activities that victimize consumers.  Please contact the AG at the following: California Department of Justice Office of the Attorney General.
15. We also suggest you contact the Internet Crime Complaint Center (IC3) which is a partnership between the Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI), the National White Collar Crime Center (NW3C), and the Bureau of Justice Assistance (BJA).  The FBI's IC3 Unit is organized to handle internet business fraud.
16. You can also try to contact the Santa Clara Police department declaring THEFT if Mochahost.com has stolen or prevented access to your own data on their servers.
    Mochahost.com
    2880 Zanker Rd #203
    San Jose, CA 95134
    (888) 816-6242 
    Phone: 888-816-6242 ext2

Answer (score 1):

A couple of google searches don't bring up the most favourable reviews.

My experiences with webhosts are that you only find out the true value of them when something goes wrong - which invariably they do from time to time. Looking at the website support the only contact number mentions a callback. This would suggest when something does go wrong getting to speak to someone in person might be difficult.

Comment: Also, no-one can guarantee 100% uptime.

Comment: @paulmorriss - Ya, I had the same thought.  That does seem to diminish their credibility.

Comment: You can't guarantee 100% uptime, but you _can_ have a 100% uptime SLA if you're set up properly. This just means that any time there's any kind of downtime (even for just one minute in 10 years), the SLA agreement spells out some kind of compensation. And for a company to offer such an SLA, they'd need to have a really robust network with lots of redundancy to avoid SLA violation penalties eating up their profits.

Comment: Also, using callbacks isn't necessarily a bad thing for high level customer support. In fact, for large web hosts, you're more likely to find good customer support with companies that employ callbacks rather than immediate 24/7 phone support. Web hosting support is not quite the same as customer service for cellphone service or ISP tech support. With web hosting, competent tech support requires deep knowledge in a wide range of topics varying from networking to system administration/server configurations to security to programming.

Comment: To provide this depth of knowledge on call 24/7 without any kind of CRM or support ticketing system to filter/route support requests would effectively mean employing a separate IT team dedicated to just manning the phones all day long. It's just not practical to do this, especially when only a small number of support requests are true emergencies requiring live phone support to fix. I'd much prefer callbacks or quick-response email support from highly trained specialists than 24/7 phone access to a call center staffed with entry-level support staff.